# How can I detect when an NSTimer changes every minute?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I'm using an NSTimer to call a method at a specific timer interval, usually more than ten minutes, but if varies. I have a timer label that shows how many minutes are remaining and I'm trying to figure out the best way to update that label whenever the minute value of the timer updates. The only two ways I can think of feel a little hacky...

1. Use two timers, one to manage the amount of time before calling
   the method and a separate timer that is recreated every minute to
   update the label.
2. Use one timer that is recreated every minute
   and manually keep track of how much time has elapsed so I know when
   to call the method.

Any other ideas?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a single `NSTimer` (I guess this counts as your option #2, but slightly expanded):

- When you want to schedule a method to be called in the future, calculate the time `targetTime` when the method needs to run.
- Start `NSTimer` set at the earlier of `now + 1 minute` and `targetTime`.
- When the timer fires, compare the current time to `targetTime`. If we're there, run the target method; otherwise, reschedule the timer at the earlier of `now + 1 minute` and `targetTime` again.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a KVO-compliant property for the timer duration, with a custom setter that invalidates the timer (if one already exists), throws it away, and creates and schedules a new timer with the new duration.

(Alternatively, observe the property from another object that owns the timer. One object holds the time interval, the other holds the timer. You can then keep the synthesized setter; you'd create/recreate the timer in the observer method.)

Then, in the controller that owns the field, observe that property, and update the field whenever the property changes.